# Blackberry: how to test on device?

Tags: blackberry, device, sign, distribute

I develop an app in BlackBerry JDE 4.5, I use ksoap library too.
When I try to test the app in simulators, I need to Load two files:

1. ksoap2.cdo
2. MyApp.cdo

But. if I want to distribute for test in any device, how can I do that?

I see about sign files. I fill the form "BlackBerry Code Signing Keys Order Form", and I receive a 3 files in my email from blackberry.

How I can use this files ?
How I can sign the app to install of my device ?

Thanks.

Comment: Was there something specific in the instructions that came with the keys you didn't understand?

Answer (score 2):

When you receive signing keys the email you receive contains text along with the attached files. This text describes usage of these attached files.

There are several ways to distribute the application to the beta-testers.

The first: generate alx file and distribute it along with cod files. This file-set can be installed via BlackBerry Desktop Manager to usb-connected device.

The second: generate jad file, and locate cod and jad files on the web-server, and open jad-file location in your BlackBerry device browser. You will get a screen with application information and "Download" button. Click on this button, and the application will be installed on the device.

Third: Install the application remotely on devices via BlackBerry Enterprise Server.

Answer (score 1):

The following tutorial will help how to install and code sign.

http://berrytutorials.blogspot.com/2009/10/code-signing-setting-up-eclipse-to-use.html

After code sign copy the .cod file which found in deliverables->Standard folder and create

alx file.For creating alx file find below link.

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/7693/Elements_and_attributes_for_alx_files_513046_11.jsp.

For installing application you need Blackbry Desktop Manager.